# Alternatives to Gaussian Process for spatial count data

Tags: gaussian-process, count-data, spatial

I have some 1-D spatially distributed count data, and I'd like to model it as a function of a relatively smooth latent variable. I've managed to get a version of this to work using a Gaussian process in Stan, but I'm wondering if there might be a simpler, more appropriate or faster alternative, since my data differ somewhat from the usual GP use case:

- It's discrete by nature (counts along the genome) and every point is observed.
- The latent variable I'd like to fit varies between 1 and 0 (ie not actually Gaussian).
- I'm only interested in having some local structure (~5 observations either side), I don't need any kinds of fancy kernels or long-distance